# Unable to see "My Magento U" on left side navigation to access learning portal

Tags: magento2, magento-u-courses

I just bought Magento 2 training courses by registering at this [link](https://u.magento.com/magento-2).

I got a mail with below information.

> Once logged into your account, go to http://training.magento.com to
>   access your My Magento U training portal. (Alternatively, you may
>   click the “My Account” link at top of page to access your Account page
>   and then click on “My Magento U” on left side navigation to access
>   your learning portal.)

I am Unable access training videos and unable to find My Magento U at -> my account -> left side.

Any one can help me on this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue there is a delay before it shows up.

See this tweet: https://twitter.com/magentou/status/804397084556148740